# Perfboad question

Tags: board, printed

I am still confused about working with perf board and solder. but I want to ask, this question:

When adding 2 electronic element on a perf board, in series, the start point of element 2 should be in same line of the end point of element 1, horizontally, or in the same vertical line?

Comment: Wherever the metal connects them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends on the type of perfboard you are using - I assume that the perfboard you are using is the type known as stripboard, with metal connecting each hole to easily connect components, like this

[image: picture of s]

If it is like this, simply put the "end" of "element 1" and the "start" of "element 2" on the same row(where the metal connects them).

However, you could be using perfboard which does not have metal bridging each hole, like this

[image: A picture of normal perfboard]

In this case, just put the "end" of one component and the "start" of another next to eachother, and bridge the two with solder.

Comment: Thanks man, that's what I am looking for, but I have a question: when I finish my board that it contains volume button and start button, how to design s box to put all board inside it, and let only the buttons appear to client ?